# Is there physical reason for a stably causal spacetime, or the existence of a Cauchy surface?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, topology, singularities, cosmic-censorship

In their 1979 essay Global structure of spacetimes, Geroch and Horowitz describe methods of determining the topology, causal structure and singularity of spacetimes. Their (mathematical) arguments are based on assumptions like stable causality (or similar), the existence of a Cauchy surface (or compact slice), genericity, etc. On the basis of cosmic censorship, they also argue about the physicality of these assumptions. Has their been progress in answering the questions about which assumptions are physically reasonable? What are the main references, since 1979?